# Why does tensorflow.rank always return shape with null value

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Being a beginner to TensorFlow **I couldn't get why does tensorflow.rank always return shape with null value?**

**This is what I am working on:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
%tensorflow_version 2.x

list_2d = [[1,2,3,4],
             [5,6,7,8],
             [9,10,11,12]
]
tensor_2d = tf.Variable(list_2d)

print(tensor_2d.shape)
print(tf.rank(tensor_2d))
```

**and the output is**

```
(3, 4)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

So **my question is what is this `shape=()` from `tf.rank` output**?

I couldn't get much from here - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/rank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the output of `tf.rank()` is a tensor itself. Instead of returning the rank as an integer, the output is a tensor with a single int32 value that represents the rank of the given input tensor. The shape `()` is the shape of the output value, not the input tensor (single value tensors have shape `()`).

Answer (score 1):

The returned value represents the number of required indices to uniquely address each element (in your case 2). And 2 is a 0-dim tensor which explains why shape is null. Refer to the documentation for more infos.